# Java: Javascript method in if-else condition on textfield onkeydown not being called

Tags: javascript, java, wicket

I am calling a javascript method `mehtod1()` on wicket components in html. I have to call the method based on the selected option in dropdown.

```
<select wicket:id="user.type" id="user.type">
        <option>dummy</option>
</select>

<input type="text" wicket:id="identity" id="identity"
    onkeydown="if(document.getElementById('user.type').options[document.getElementById('user.type').selectedIndex].value=='52')return method1('abc');
    else return method1('xyz');"/>
```

But if-else condition is not working. If I remove this condition and just call the `method1()` then it works fine. I think `getElementById` is not working and that's why the condition is skipped and the `method1()` is not called at all.

Java:

```
identityField = (TextField<String>) new TextField<String>("identity", new Model()).add(new ErrorIndicator());
identityField.setOutputMarkupId(true);

userTypeDropDown = (LocalizableLookupDropDownChoice<String>) new LocalizableLookupDropDownChoice<String>("user.type", String.class, "abc", this,
            false, true, mobBasePage.getLocale()).setNullValid(true).add(new ErrorIndicator());
userTypeDropDown.setDefaultModel(new Model<String>());
userTypeDropDown.setRequired(true);
userTypeDropDown.setOutputMarkupId(true);
userTypeDropDown.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I cannot remove `setOutputMarkupId(true)` as I need to call ajax on the component as well.

Comment: Try inspecting your `<select>` element in browser; does its `id` attribute have `user.type` value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
userTypeDropDown.setMarkupId("user.type");
```

add this.. this will solve your problem.